# Rails ElasticSearch model with fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, mongoid

I'm using [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails) and [mongoid](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid)
I have the following simple mapping with fields:

```
"title": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                 "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 }
              }
           }
```

My model looks like this:

```
class ArticlesEvent
include Mongoid::Document
include Elasticsearch::Model

field :title, type: String

attr_accessible :title

def as_indexed_json(options={})
  as_json(except: [:id, :_id])
end
```

Can anyone show an example how to define the rails model with the title.raw field, and how to access  that field? Since the multi fields have been deprecated it's hard to find a working example with rails and mongoid.

Thanks

Comment: Note that [multi fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#_multi_fields_3) are not deprecated, they are well and alive. What was deprecated in version 1.0 was the [`multi-field` **type**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html), which can now simply be a `string` type with an embedded `fields`  structure, i.e. exactly what you have above.

Comment: ok thanks, do you have a rails example of that?

Comment: Yes, it's shown in my answer below.

Comment: See my comment, it throws an exception....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is still an open issue with elasticsearch-rails: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/79

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this with the following attribute definition in your model:

```
attribute :title, String, mapping: { 
    fields: {
       raw:  { type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed' }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm using Mongoid, and this code throws an exception: "undefined method `attribute' for ArticlesEvent:Class"

Answer (score 0):

You can define below mapping in your model

```html
indexes :name_of_field,type: :keyword, fields: {
    raw: {
      type: :text
    }
  }
```